# Kotlin plugin error: Could not generate a proxy class for class MyTask

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have created Gradle plugin written in Kotlin but after I had included it into my project I faced following error:

```
Failed to apply plugin [id 'my-plugin']
    Could not generate a proxy class for class MyTask
```

This is code of my plugin, I was using custom gradle task

```
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

  override fun apply(project: Project) {
    with(project.tasks) {
        create("uploadTask", MyTask::class.java)
    }
  }
}

class MyTask : DefaultTask() {

  @TaskAction
  fun run() {
      println("Running ...")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When I run `./gradlew build --stacktrace` I got the cause

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class ....
```

As classes in kotlin are final by default, the solution was easy, just change my task declaration to:

```
open class MyTask : DefaultTask()
```